# deserializing messages from msmq send via netmsmq binding

Tags: serialization, netmsmqbinding

We have wcf service and on error we send messages to "poison" queue using netmsmq binding rather than using System.Messaging's Send Method().

We tried fetching those message out of that poison queue but when deserializing i got a lot of junk data with hexadecimal values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can deserialize by using BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement

Please read 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c03d80cd-492c-4ece-8890-6a35b12352e0